# Regions in webforms asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am new to asp.net, I want to define #Region in my .cs page file. Is it possible to that in web pages. I know it can be done in winforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `#region` tags in your code behind files the same way you can in any `.cs` file - it makes no difference if they are in a web project or any other project.

You can't define them in the `.aspx` page.

In your `.cs` code behind file:

```
#region "Name of region"

   // Code comes here

#endregion
```

Comment: can you please give me the syntax to do that.

Comment: @vaibhav - It is the _same_ syntax as any #region in C#.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't define #regions in webforms (in the ASPX file), but you can collapse tags very easily in visual studio, as long as your markup is properly defined.

Comment: He talks about "web pages" which I took to mean ASPX files, and then mentions .cs files, where the answer is somewhat obvious... Seemed like a self-contradictory question the way I read it...

Comment: @DaveMarkle  It's a 2-part question.

Answer (score 1):

```
  #region Description of the code within this region
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
  #endregion
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and it's working. Which version are you using?