# Keep javascript functions collapsed in VS2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am working with the new Visual Studio 2013 that now also has better support for embedded javascript code inside ASPX-Pages.

Since I there are some ASPX pages that have pretty much javascript code on it, I am collapsing the functions I don't need. However the next time I open the ASPX page in the editor the functions are all expanded again...

I am now asking: Does anyone know if there is a setting or something that enables to keep them collapsed, once they got collapsed by me? Just like it works for methods / classes collapsed in .cs files.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825720/regions-in-webforms-asp-net

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh This is **not** a duplicate from your posted link...

Comment: actually you can't create regions/expandables in asp.net markup. this what the above post has answered.

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh **If you would read my question, you would realise that I am not talking about regions!**

Comment: sorry, i missed that part. I believe your concern is valid apart from regions.

Answer (score 1):

I also could not find a direct solution for this, so I looked up information regarding macros in Visual Studio. I found that recording the collapse operation (Ctrl+M) on the specified functions and running this macro at each startup solved my problem temporarily, but not after extensive change in my code.

I would recommend looking into parametering macros for an easy to maintain, semi-automatic code-collapse on startup. This is not a read-and-go answer, but it can give you some hints on where to start a workaround.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I don't know how I didn't notice this, but PHPTools for Visual Studio in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate keeps these settings.